# JQ filter specific item based on inner item

Tags: jq

Having the following Array

```
[
  [
    { "field" : { "name": "appname" }, "value": { "value" : "app1" } },
    { "field" : { "name": "appstat" }, "value": { "value" : "UP"   } }
  ],
  [
    { "field" : { "name": "appname" }, "value": { "value" : "app2" } },
    { "field" : { "name": "appstat" }, "value": { "value" : "DOWN" } }
  ],
  [
    { "field" : { "name": "appname" }, "value": { "value" : "app3" } },
    { "field" : { "name": "appstat" }, "value": { "value" : "READY"} }
  ]
]
```

I want to be able to select on specific items based on the appname.

So i can do for example

jq .[] app3

response should be ***READY***

Comment: Your input json is invalid. Also, what did you try? Where did you got stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should bring you there

```sh
jq -r --arg q "app3" '
  .[]
  | select(.[] | .field.name == "appname" and .value.value == $q)
  | .[]
  | select(.field.name == "appstat").value.value
'
```

```
READY
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/eroNIiWjfh)

---

However, your data structure seems rather complicated. You'd be better off (at least for this use case) with a simpler array of objects to lookup key-value pairs. For example, transform your input like so:

```sh
jq 'map(map({(first(.field.name)): first(.value.value)}) | add)'
```

```json
[
  {
    "appname": "app1",
    "appstat": "UP"
  },
  {
    "appname": "app2",
    "appstat": "DOWN"
  },
  {
    "appname": "app3",
    "appstat": "READY"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/SoDxbc9S-l)

That way, your lookup would be as simple as

```sh
jq -r --arg q "app3" '.[] | select(.appname == $q).appstat'
```

```
READY
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jinW809fVV)

Comment: Thank you!! Exactly what was needed.

Comment: Ah, yes i know it would be simplier, but this is how HAPROXY stats output, so need to work with the provided data